# Localized function arguments and names

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

We would like to make our custom functions' names and arguments to be localizable.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You localize the entire Metadata file. Then, you reference each such file from the manifest.

Your `CustomFunctions` sections remains invariant, like this:

```xml
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
                        <Script>
                            <SourceLocation resid="residScript" />
                        </Script>
                        <Page>
                            <SourceLocation resid="residPage"/>
                        </Page>
                        <Metadata>
                            <SourceLocation resid="residMetadata" />
                        </Metadata>
                        <Namespace resid="residNS" />
                    </ExtensionPoint>
```

And then in the `Resources` section, you have an Override for each supported locale:

```xml
                <bt:Url id="residMetadata" DefaultValue="https://your.cdn.com/metadata/en_us">
                    <bt:Override Locale="bg-bg" Value="https://your.cdn.com/metadata/bg_bg" />
                    <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="https://your.cdn.com/metadata/fr_fr" />
                </bt:Url>
```

Keep in mind that there is more to localize than just names - there is descriptions, support URLs, eventually icons.

It is also possible that functions may need to have different implementations in different geomarkets/locales. That's why you can localize the `Script` file as well.

You localize the namespace in a similar way, except it is a plain string, not a URL:

```xml
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="residNS" DefaultValue="default.namespace">
                    <bt:Override Locale="bg-bg" Value="българско.именно.пространство" />
                    <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="espace.des.noms.francais" />
                </bt:String>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you! 

So AFAIU there is no way to use this with a JS-based i18n solution like i18next? I currently use that to localize JS strings, and it would have been better to keep everything in one place.

Additionally, our metadata JSON is generated by the custom-functions-metadata-plugin. No dice to use that anymore, I'll need to support metadata by hand from now on?